# Html Javascript / Input-Output

Tags: javascript, html, input, output

As you can see in my code I'm trying to get the material information by filling width and depth. For example, width:300 and depth:300 will result 90000. Then, if you write your result to other input you can get the material information.

I don't want to write result to another input to get this information. I just want to multiply width and depth and according to result, I'd like to see the material.

Demo link: https://tender-tereshkova-bab7de.netlify.app/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>javascript: calculate two numbers</title>
    <meta charset="windows-1252" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <script>
      function calc() {
        var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n1').value);
        var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n2').value);

        document.getElementById('output').value = n1 * n2;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>FILL IN WIDTH AND DEPTH</p>
    <p>
      Widht <input type="text" id="n1" /> <br /><br />
      Depth <input type="text" id="n2" />
    </p>

    <button onclick="calc();">Get Result</button>
    <input type="text" border-style="none" id="output" />

    <br /><br /><br /><br />

    Fill your result <input id="first_name" />
    <button
      onclick="document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = getStudentReport(getStudent())"
      id="output"
    >
      Find Material
    </button>

    <hr />
    <div id="result"></div>

    <script>
      var students = [
        {
          name: '105000',
          track: 'Aluminium ',
          points: 'Dark Blue',
        },
        {
          name: '90000',
          track: 'Stainless',
          points: 'Dark Grey',
        },
      ];

      function print(message) {
        var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
        outputDiv.innerHTML = message;
      }

      function getStudent() {
        var student = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
        if (student != null) {
          for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            if (students[i].name.toLowerCase() === student.toLowerCase()) {
              return students[i];
            }
          }
        }

        return null;
      }

      function getStudentReport(student) {
        if (student == null) {
          return '';
        }

        var report = '<h2>Material: ' + student.track + '</h2>';

        report += '<p>Color: ' + student.points + '</p>';

        return report;
      }

      function say_hi() {
        var student = document.getElementById('first_name').value;

        if (student.name === students) {
          message = getStudentReport(student);
          print(message);
        }

        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = html;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the material without the extra step, you can calculate the product of the two numbers and right after that find the item in your array. Once it's found, you can update the result.

I've created a snippet for you below. I've made a lot of changes:

- I've separated the HTML and JS parts.
- I've wrapped the inputs in a `form`, and added [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) for the inputs.
- I've changed the input type to number (as these fields can only be numbers)
- I've renamed the `students` array to `items`.
- I've changed the `name` property to `size` in your and it's no longer a string but a number, so it's easier to work with later. The product of `depth` and `width` is a number, so it's easier to compare to another number.
- Instead of different button clicks, we're checking the form [`submit` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) by using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). This way, you can hit enter in any field, and submit the form. It's also easier to get the form fields by using [`event.target.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements).
- I've removed unnecessary functions
- I've used [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment): `let { depth, width } = e.target.elements`.
- I've used [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to write the HTML part in JS with variables.

You can click on the "Run code Snippet" button below and see the result :)

```js
// students is renamed to items as I'm sure these were not students
let items = [{
    // size is now a number, so it's easier to work with
    size: 105000,
    material: 'Aluminium',
    color: 'Dark Blue',
    image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/wpOnFM9hjNI/300x300',
  },
  {
    size: 90000,
    material: 'Stainless',
    color: 'Dark Grey',
    image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/LKiB35E8iGA/300x300',
  },
];

// instead of listening to button clicks we listen to form submit
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit)

function handleSubmit(event) {
  // prevent page reload
  event.preventDefault();
  // get the form elements
  let {
    depth,
    width
  } = event.target.elements;

  // multiply the fields' values
  let product = parseFloat(depth.value) * parseFloat(width.value);
  // get the item by size
  let item = getItem(product);
  // if there is an item found
  let result = item
    ? `<h2>Material: ${item.material}</h2>
 <p>Color: ${item.color}</p>
 <img src="${item.image}" alt="">`
    : `<h2>Oh, noes!</h2>
 <p>No item found</p>`;

  // render the result
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
}

function getItem(size) {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].size === size) {
      return items[i];
    }
  }
  // if we didn't find anything
  return null;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>FILL IN WIDTH AND DEPTH</p>
  <label>Width <input type="number" name="width" required /></label>
  <label>Depth <input type="number" name="depth" required /></label>
  <button type="submit">Find material</button>
</form>
<hr>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Hey man! Thank you for responding. It helped me a lot. If I want too add img to result items What do I have to add ? Thank you again...

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If you want to add images, you can add the links to the images and create an `img` tag in `result`. I've updated the snippet above.

Comment: Cool! If you dont mind I just want to add one more thing. 
- If result size is between 90000 and 100000 I want to see Aluminium material information.
- If result size is between 100001 and 120000 I want to see Stainless material information.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do that yourself. Instead of `size` add a `min` and a `max` property and in the `getItem`'s for loop check if the value is between these two variables. (`if (size >= items[i].min && size <= items[i].max) {...`)

Comment: Allright thank you man. Im gonna try according to your orientation. Please do not misunderstand me. I am not trying to make you do all things. Im just new on this stuffs and trying to improve myself by looking how it works.

Comment: No worries, you can do it ;)